# Javascript setinterval and clearinterval

Tags: javascript, image, html, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to make a image seem that it is falling down. So I made a div and put the image in it. Using setinterval and clearinterval I'm trying to get the image to stop at the border of the div but I don't know how to do this.
here is the code:

```
var x = 200;
var y = -155;
var inc = 5;

var myVar;

var fall = function() {
myVar = setInterval(function(){moveDown();},30);
};
var stopFall = function() {
clearInterval(myVar);
};
var moveDown = function() {
y += inc;

document.getElementById('img1').style.top = y + 'px';
};
```

I want the `setinterval` to stop automatically when `y = 155` but I don't know how. I've tried if, while and for statements but they don't seem to work..
I made a button that runs `stopFall();` and it works, but I want it to stop automatically without clicking any button. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: why dont you try http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/

Answer (score 2):

Change your `moveDown()` function to check for the current state of `y` and, if necessary, call `stopFall()`.

```
var moveDown = function() {
  y += inc;

  if ( y >= 155 ) { stopFall(); }

  document.getElementById('img1').style.top = y + 'px';
};
```

As an alternative you could use `clearInterval()` directly like this

```
var moveDown = function() {
  y += inc;

  if ( y >= 155 ) { 
    clearInterval(myVar);
  }

  document.getElementById('img1').style.top = y + 'px';
};
```

Comment: Oh god thank you so much!
ahhaha I never expected it to be so simple...thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var x = 200;
 var y = -155;
 var inc = 5;

 var myVar;

 var fall = function() {
       myVar = setInterval(function(){
         if(y >= 155) clearInterval(myVar);
         moveDown();
       },
       30);
 };

 var moveDown = function() {
     y += inc;

     document.getElementById('img1').style.top = y + 'px';
 };
```